# How to install qt3-dev-tools package

Tags: apt, 13.10, qt3

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and want to install qt3-dev-tools package. When i run this command

```
sudo apt-get install qt3-dev-tools
```

i am getting this error,

```
E: Unable to locate package qt3-dev-tools
```

Please help me.

Comment: Can you post the output of `sudo apt-get update` to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You may install it from precise repository. I tried this in 14.04, it installs fine but I didn't try building any source using it.

1. Add precise repository

   ```
   echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main universe multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/precise.list
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. Install `qt3-dev-tools`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install qt3-dev-tools
   ```
3. Remove the repository.

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/precise.list
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

Comment: This worked for me to compile `lprof`. I needed to additionally install `qt3-apps-dev`, and then all required qt3-related packages were present. And `lprof` even starts successfully after this :)

Comment: Actually, in my case it was sufficient to use this repo to install `lprof` itself. But at least I've tested that Qt3 development packages work.

Answer (score 0):

qt3-dev-tools not available in Ubuntu 13.10 . Lucid & precise have it.If you want you can install qt4-dev-tools.

but if you want to install in manual way then

http://www.develer.com/~naufraghi/PyQt3Support/PyQt3Support-PyQt4.4.4-gpl-r4.tar.gz download and install from source.

Comment: Your link is broken. Do you have an up to date one?

Comment: @Seth thanks for notifying. give me time. I will update.

Comment: Possibly this: https://github.com/develersrl/pyqt3support

Comment: That looks like Python bindings. Do you have a link to something that will install plain qt3 libs and dev libs for Mint 18. I need it to compile pdfedit