# Edit an ICC profile

Tags: colors, icc

My laptop monitor is currently set up with an existing ICC profile, however, the color temperature is somewhat annoying at the default 6400K value. After some testing I found out, that 6000K is quite good, but setting it everytime with `redshift` is hacky.

So the solution would be editing the ICC profile itself. For this I have tried to use `colormgr` without success. Does anybody know a solution?

Answer (score 6):

Jolly good question. I have only managed to find [LProf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lprof/), which claims to be the only open source ICC profile editor.

> LProf is an open source color profiler that creates ICC compliant profiles for devices such as cameras, scanners and monitors. Origanally authored by Marti Maria the creator of LCMS. Marti has graciously consented to the creation of this project.

Unfortunately, there is no repository or .deb file so far so you would need to compile it. The dependencies stated in the readme file seem reasonable, although it does require LCMS itself with which I am not familiar at all, and this is where I left it.

I overcame my problem by browsing similar ICC profiles for my device in sites such as [ICC Profiles and Monitor Settings Database](http://www.tftcentral.co.uk/articles/icc_profiles.htm) and I ended up keeping the one that suits me best.

Comment: Yes, I also solved my original problem using that database. Will take a look on **LProf** though. If I manage to compile it, I will get back to you.

Comment: `lprof` can be compiled using `qt3-dev-tools` and `qt3-apps-dev` from Ubuntu Precise repo, see [this answer}(https://askubuntu.com/a/788211/113421) for instructions how to add it to your system.

Comment: Oh, actually if you go that route, you can simply install `lprof` package from the repo.