# How to install qt3 in ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04, qt3

It seems that qt3 does not have a candidate in Ubuntu 14 software repository. How can I install qt3 on my system?

I have a software that needs qt3.

Also looked at this thread that has no working solution: [How to install qt3-dev-tools package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/386254/how-to-install-qt3-dev-tools-package)

Comment: Same thing here. Any luck?